# Inno setup: uninstall everything installed

Tags: inno-setup

I have a iss script that installs a lot of DLLs in `{sys}` directory. How can I tell inno to delete everything just installed there when uninstalling? It's boring and error prone to explicitly declare "to be deleted" files one by one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Inno will automatically uninstall anything that it installed, unless you have specifically told it not to with specific `Flags`.  So you shouldn't need to do anything explicitly.

Note that there may be special requirements for installing files into `{sys}` (in particular you should strongly consider using the `sharedfile` flag), and certain components may require very specific settings to work properly.

Also note that in general you should not install anything to `{sys}` unless specifically instructed to do so by the vendor of the component in question.  (You should never install your own application-private components there, for example.)